# Cocoa: How to set window title?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a Cocoa application with a secondary window created using a subclass of NSWindowController. I wish to set the window title. The documented method call is setTitle:. I have called this from within the window controller as follows:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    // set window title
    [[self window] setTitle:@"test string"]; 
}
```

This does not affect the title of the window though.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is that method getting called?

Answer (score 18):

You can connect Your window with IBOutlet and then change Your code:

```
[[self window] setTitle:@"test string"];
```

**To this:**

```
[yourWindow setTitle:@"test string"];
```

Full code for example:

.h

```
IBOutlet NSWindow *yourWindow; //Don't forget to connect window to this
```

.m

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [yourWindow setTitle:@"test string"];
}
```

---

**And of course You can change title not programatically:**

Title can be changed in *Attributes inspector*:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to do that. `NSWindowController` already has a `window` outlet, you just need to connect that.

Comment: I tried it with that outlet (see initial post) with no affect.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using another outlet instead of the default 'window' from the NSWindowController functions correctly. Can anyone explain this behavior

Comment: Many apologies for wasting peoples time better used elsewhere, I did not have the window connected in IB. Apologies again

Answer (score 5):

The NSWindowController class reference indicates that to customize the title, you should override the `windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName:` method.

Answer (score 4):

I just use

```
self.window?.title = "Some String"
```

where I create the window.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift this is can be done with: `someOutlet.title = "New Title"`

Here is an example that lives in your window controller class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentOutlet: NSWindow!

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()

    contentOutlet.title = "New Title"
}
```

Again, remember to connect the outlet to the window, or just drag an outlet from the window to your window controller class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a non-document based app using the latest Xcode when binding the title to a selected objects filename.  Whenever there is no selection the title shows up as "Untitled" - which makes no senses in the application.

So I created two properties in the NSWindowController - one gets bound to the selected object's filename and the other gets bound to the Window title.

In the didSet{} method of the property bound to the selected object I check for nil value and set the title property to the application name.  If it's not nil then I set the property to the selected objects filename.

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    /// Bind this to the controllers selected objects filename property
        @objc dynamic var filename: String? {
            didSet {
                if let name = filename {
                    title = name
                } else {
                    title = "IAM2 - no selection"
                }
            }
            
        }
        /// Bind this to the windows title
        @objc dynamic var title: String = "IAM2"


     override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    
    
    
    self.bind(NSBindingName(rawValue: "filename"),
              to: self.controller,
              withKeyPath: "selectedObject.filename",
              options: nil)
    
    self.window?.bind(NSBindingName(rawValue: "title"),
              to: self,
              withKeyPath: "title",
              options: nil)
    
    self.window?.bind(NSBindingName(rawValue: "subtitle"),
              to: controller,
              withKeyPath: "rootPath",
              options: nil)
    
}

}
```